# Django: records creation statistics charts

Tags: python, django, charts, statistics

I'm looking for a way to implement statistics feature for the admin user in my Django application.
Recently I was thinking about fetching data manually, counting the number of records created per week, month, year etc. but now I'm looking at doing this stuff with django-chartit.

May be someone already solved this task?

Sultan

Comment: The chartit documentation seems pretty clear. Can you explain what you've tried and what issues you're having?